# How to achieved switch/open to div same as href="#tabs-3" in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I
I have below html line.

```
 <a href="#tabs-3" onclick="CallFunc()">d</a>
```

replaced with below line:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="CallFunc()">d</a>
```

Inside `CallFunc()` , i need to write jquery which will give me same function as `href="#tab-3"`
(so, switch to that tab)

Please share me how it is achieve in jquery ?
When we click at `href="#tab-3` then it page just switch to that particular DIV, due to some UI design, i needed to remove this line from UI though need to maintain that feature using JQUERY, so, what is equivalent jquery ?

Comment: Not getting man.. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your `CallFunc()` this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({active: 2}); //it will make your 3rd tab active
```

And if you want to set it after the plugin's initialization do this:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 ); //just select the right tab as the third parameter
```

More Info: [Tabs Widget Doc options:active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

Also you can leave the tabs, and fire `CallFunc()` in the `activate` event.

> activate( event, ui )Type: tabsactivate
>
> Triggered after a tab has been activated (after animation completes).
>   If the tabs were previously collapsed, ui.oldTab and ui.oldPanel will
>   be empty jQuery objects. If the tabs are collapsing, ui.newTab and
>   ui.newPanel will be empty jQuery objects.

[Tabs Widget Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)